# Tables in KDoc?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

We usually have changelog in our Java DTO's that consists of a table defined in Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Changelog:
 *
 * <table>
 *     <tr><th>Version</th><th>Description</th></tr>
 *     <tr>
 *         <td>2</td>
 *         <td>Added field 'something'</td>
 *     </tr>
 *     <tr>
 *         <td>3</td>
 *         <td>Added field 'somethingElse'</td>
 *     </tr>
 * </table>
 */
public class MyDTO {
 ...
}
```

This renders (in Intellij using Javadoc preview) nicely into something like this:

[image]

Now we want to do the same thing for our Kotlin data classes. Reading up on the docs of [KDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup) where it says:

> For inline markup, KDoc uses the regular Markdown syntax, extended to support a shorthand syntax for linking to other elements in the code.

So I've tried to create a table using Markdown syntax:

```
/**
 * Changelog:
 *
 *| Version       | Description                 |
 *| ------------- | --------------------------  |
 *| 2             | Added field 'something'     |
 *| 3             | Added field 'somethingElse' |
 *
 */
data class MyKotlinDTO(..) { 
    ...
}
```

But this renders (again using Intellij preview):

[image]

Which doesn't look like a table.

I've also tried just using an HTML table but that doesn't work either.

**Question**

Does KDoc support tables and if so how do you create one?

Comment: As of today, and probably since June 2021 (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/pull/1589) this is supported in KDoc and in IntelliJ just as the OP wants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently KDoc does not support tables - there are issues opened  on [Github](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/199)  and [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16228)

There is some kind of workaround - you can surround text with **```** (triple backticks) to keep indentations and formatting

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround is to generate a table with [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). For example,

[image]

Then paste into your documentation,

[image]

Comment: However, this is not a table, but – just as in Alex’ answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075998/2621917 – preformatted text.